# Fetch data from DynamoDB in JSON format using .NET

Tags: asp.net, json, httprequest, amazon-dynamodb

I want to fetch data from Amazon DynamoDB in JSON format in a .NET application. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: JSON I want to add looks like :
UserGuid = "db7065de-5ad1-420d-9c3c-2420ef9b8f46"
PreferenceKey = "Alert_5"
UserProvider = "Viper"

Frequency = "real-time"

RuleType = "IDDN"

ActionType = "Email"

Comment: Welcome to [so]. It appears the JSON hasn't been added properly. You can edit the post to add your JSON instead of placing it in a comment.